# Removing Navigation Bar When Going Back

Tags: c#, android, ios, windows-phone, xamarin.forms

I have a navigation page in Xamarin.Forms, and it's working. I have a start page (page 1), which isn't supposed to have a navigation bar. And I have another page accessed by the start page (page 2), which is supposed to have a navigation bar. When I go from page 1, to page 2 the navigation bar appears with a back button (which I want). However, when I go rom page 2, to page 1, the navigation bar remains (which I don't want). How do I prevent the navigation bar from being visible on page 1 after the user has entered and left page 2? P.S. in the constructors of page 1 and 2, I used this line of code:

```
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar (this, true);
```

or

```
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar (this, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;

decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```